# checking if subject exist through jquery in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

How can I do this in ruby on rails with jquery

The Code:

```
Model
  Subject

View
  <%= text_field_tag :subject_1 %>
  <%= text_field_tag :subject_2 %>
  <%= text_field_tag :subject_3 %>
```

Senario:

> User typed the subject code on the textfield(subject_1) and if the user goes to the next text field(subject_2) beside the first textfield(subject_1) there will be a reload icon then show the corresponding subject details(subject name, subject code, subject schedule) base on the typed suject code. And if the subject is does not exist it will show a message "Subject does not exist.".

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that when a `blur` event occurs in the `subject1` `text_field` an AJAX call is made to the server that tries to find a subject record with the id/description/attribute given by the `text_field´ and returns success or error. The code would be something like this:

```
$('subject_1').blur(function() {
  var field_value = $(this).val();
  $.post("/subjects/validate_subject", field_value, function(data) {
    success: function() {
      // Here you populate the subject_2 text_field with the data from the server.
    },
    error: function() {
      // Here you populate some error content in your view.
    }
  });
});
```

Remember to add the `validate_subject` to your `routes.rb`.
This is just the beginning of the answer to your problem. I recommend you to read about Rails and Ajax interaction.
Here is a great guide for this subject. http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/

Comment: What will I put on my controller?

Comment: The `validate_subject` method that searchs for subjects and return a success or error response depending on the search results.

Comment: This is what my validate_subject method on my subject controller contains: 
@subject = Subject.find_by_sc_id(params[:subject1])

How is data being proccessed here?